# ZF3 Event Manager works only for EVENT_DISPATCH

Tags: events, zend-framework3

In a ZF3 custom module, I need to intercept some events.

In the `module.config.php`, the function `init()` is :

```
public function init(ModuleManager $manager)
{        
    $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager();    
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'onDispatch'], 100);
    $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, [$this, 'onDispatchError'], 110);
}
```

In the same class, there are the two functions :

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
{        
    echo 'testOnDispatch';
    die;   
}

public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event)
{        
    echo 'testOnDispatchError';
    die;        
}
```

The `EVENT_DISPATCH` event is triggered without any problem but the `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` is not. After some tests, I saw that only the `EVENT_DISPATCH` event is triggered.

In the view manager configuration, both `display_not_found_reason` and `display_exceptions` are both set to `TRUE`. If I replace `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` with `EVENT_DISPATCH` (twice `EVENT_DISPATCH`) all is working fine regarding the priority.

What did I miss?

Comment: Could simply mean that you ARE dispatching some event, somewhere and that you have no errors in the code during the dispatch event code/triggers. 

How about, in the `onDispatch` function, you do what Zend already has in the `Application` class, as a test. See your vendor packages, file: `vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php` around line #330 ([on github](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/0cb6770856885ca916b44798e3ae37547a20b46e/src/Application.php#L334)). Also do [the event tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/event-manager/#getting-started). Gl & hf

Comment: rkeet, thank for your reply. It makes sense for `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR`. Meanwhile, as an example, `EVENT_FINISH` does not work also. That event should be dispatched in any case when the MVC is finished, right ?

Comment: Theoretically: yes. However, find where it's implemented to see if it's even called anywhere. If you're using PhpStorm you can find its declaration with Ctrl + click (on constant, or "Cmd" on apple). Doing the same (Ctrl/Cmd + click) on the constant declaration will show (or ask to show) all implementations of said constant. Look through the results to see if it's used. From the github link (prev comment), it would be along the lines of `$events->triggerEvent($event);` find somewhere that `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` is used that isn't `const EVENT_DISPATCH`.

Comment: I followed your advice, I've found in `zendframework\zend-mvc\src\SendResponseListener.php` at line #74 where the `EVENT_FINISH` is registered ( only once ) and the call back function `sendResponse` is actually called. I've also found the function `triggerListeners` in `zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php` at line #283. I checked the name of the events and yes, events like `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` on route error or  `EVENT_FINISH` are triggered. What is interesting in this function is that the count `$listOfListenersByPriority` is 1. So, I feel that my listener in the module is not attached.

Comment: I've found a workaround here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162931/zf3-onroute-event-listener/42205661#42205661] Not sure if it's a bug or a feature ... Anyway, thank for your help. Following your advices I learned a lot of possibilites.

Comment: You're welcome. If you figured out a solution it would be great if you could post a small workable solution to your question as an answer. Others might stumble upon your question and be helped out by your solution. To lessen the amount of work you might have to do in the future, to create listeners and handle events, have a look at a question of my own of last year, concerning the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056684/1155833.